# What is this technique called, of eerily blinking one eye then the other? Or is it just an actor's improvisation?

Tags: dune-2021

[image]
[image]

In the movie, ***Dune***, When Piter De Vries meets a Sardaukar commander, requesting troops. There is a very eye-catching moment when he blinks one eye before the other eye.

This funny eye moment reminds me of Bill Skarsgard's performance in ***It***, which intends to create an uneasy and eery feeling. Not sure if there is a name for this technique.

I am wondering if Piter De Vries does it to build up his character or it is simply an improvised clever moment from the actor himself.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised at all if it's deliberate. Whether the writer, director, or actor came up with the idea, it was left in, and probably done several times over multiple takes. In terms of what it's called, "acting" seems to be the best term.

Comment: I don't remember this exact scene, but I remember a lot of characters in Dune used non-verbal signals to communicate (like hand signs and gestures). Could the character have been giving a secret signal?